# ListView (with custom adapter) - items consist of a textview and a button

Tags: android

i am kinda new in Android programming. I want to create a listview, where each item consist of a text and a empty/full favorite button (only one button is visible at the moment). The list should implement two functions:

- by clicking on the favorite button (empty or full) in an item, it should change to the button to the one currently invisible and set the visible one invisible. How should I implement a function which reacts on the click on a favorite button and "knows" which item the favorite button exists in?
- simple onItemClickListener (it doesnt react what I have right now).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post your current code ? You can have a boolean isFull  and `if(isFull){ ... do this stuff .. }`. Hard to say what you are trying to achieve without seeing the code.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi I managed somehow, but thanks anyway